# Is it possible to differentiate between a scratch buffer and a new [no name] buffer?

Tags: vim

I would like to know if there is a command I can run in vim to tell whether a particular window that has focus is actually a Scratch buffer or an empty buffer (such as when creating a new buffer that I haven't saved to a file yet).

The background for why I want to do this:

I have a special context sensitive function bound to my <kbd>Tab</kbd> key in Vim, and I'd like to further improve it by allowing it to skip the scratch buffers but not the unsaved new file buffers. I know that `@%` can get me the file that backs the buffer, but this is empty in both cases.

My current code looks like this:

```
function! NextWindowOrTabOrBuffer()
    " prefer to cycle thru only the set of windows if more than one window
    if (winnr('$') == 1 && tabpagenr('$') == 1)
        " only situation where we cycle to next buffer
        bnext
    endif
    " Rest of logic is just as sound (and simple) as it ever was
    if (winnr() == winnr('$'))
        tabnext
        1wincmd w "first window
    else
        wincmd w "next window
    endif
endfunc

function! PrevWindowOrTabOrBuffer()
    if (winnr('$') == 1 && tabpagenr('$') == 1)
        " only situation where we cycle to next buffer
        bprev
    endif
    if (winnr() == 1)
        tabprev
        let winnr = winnr('$')
        exec winnr . 'wincmd w'
    else
        wincmd W
    endif
endfunc

" I actually like the mash tab to cycle windows behavior so let's keep it simple
"nnoremap <Tab> :wincmd w<CR>
"nnoremap <S-Tab> :wincmd W<CR>

" Nevermind, I actually really need this on a small screen...
nnoremap <Tab> :call NextWindowOrTabOrBuffer()<CR>
nnoremap <S-Tab> :call PrevWindowOrTabOrBuffer()<CR>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by defining "scratch buffer" as there's no such thing in Vim. One could create a "scratch buffer" with something like:

```
:vnew | setlocal nobuflisted buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe noswapfile
```

so you could check for the value of `&buftype` or `&buflisted` or any/all of the other options.

If that "scratch buffer" was created by some third-party plugin you may have other "hooks" at your disposal like a `b:variable` or whatever.

Comment: I found that `bufhidden` is set to `wipe` for the particular "scratch buffers" that I'm interested in. I was also thinking maybe there would be something that sets (that I could retrieve and test) the word `Scratch` as it does show that as the name of the window in its statusbar. But I guess I'll just have to check the source of the plugin for that. Meanwhile I'll just make my code test for `wipe`.